# Cannot connect to a specific Ethernet port using Python and PyVisa

Tags: python, visa

I am trying to connect to a temperature chamber via an Ethernet connection using pyVisa in Python. The device only allows connections through port 2049. I have no problems connecting to it via [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) or [HyperTerminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilgraeve), but when I try this command in Python

```
import visa
chamber = visa.instrument("TCPIP::10.2.17.130::2049")
```

I get this error:

> VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND: Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system

I know the device is there because I can talk through it in PuTTY, but I cannot seem to get the Python code to work. Any hints? Does pyvisa use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) by default?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way (IMHO) to access a **VISA resource** is still by using the **VISA device detection** which would be through:

- `visa.ResourceManager().list_resources()`, if you're using `pyVisa`
- or `viFindRsrc()` and `viFindNext()` if you use the `visa32.dll` library.

Now by default, **LAN** connections are **not** detected using either method. This leaves you with two choices:

- If you have installed **NI-MAX** (the *Measurement & Automation Explorer* from *National Instruments* is a **free** download), go under *'Devices & Interfaces'*, right-click on *'Network Devices'*, select *'Create New VISA TCP/IP Resource...'* and follow the instructions. **NI-MAX** will auto detect your instrument and provide its **VISA** resource name. **Note** that now this resource will be listed by both `list_resources()` and `viFindRsrc()`/`viFindNext()`
- If not, you will have to provide **VISA** with the **right** resource name. If you use a **VISA passport** (e.g. *VICP* for LeCroy oscilloscopes) then you should change the **VISA header** appropriately (replace *TCPIP* with *VICP*). Then, the syntax is the following: **[visa-header]::[instrument-ip]::INSTR** or **[visa-header]::[instrument-ip]::[instrument-port]::INSTR**

Actually, it's not always **INSTR**, depending on the resource class (see http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvinstio/visa_resource_name_generic/).

Be sure to send **byte** strings to the instrument (especially if using **Python 3+**), otherwise you will get the following error:

> VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND: Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system

which can also be identified by `0xBFFF0011` or a return value of `-1073807343`.

Comment: Update:

The previous answer is not totally accurate anymore. The *list_resources()* takes a default parameter with value _?*::INSTR_, so it will show only resources with _INSTR_ in it. To show all resources, you can use ```visa.ResourceManager().list_resources(query='?*')```, or if you want to show only the _TCP_ resources ```visa.ResourceManager().list_resources(query='TCP?*')```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the temp chamber supports the LAN instrument protocol?

If unsure, try using raw socket instead, i.e.

```
chamber = visa.instrument("TCPIP::10.2.17.130::2049::SOCKET")
```

(pyvisa does not use SSH by default)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import socket
HOST = "10.2.17.130"    # The remote host
PORT = 2049             # The same port as used by the server

    s = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```